# Cos'è una "fascia protetta" riferito a uno sciopero?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Prendiluna*, di Stefano Benni, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Lasciò l'albergo, trascinando la valigia con quattordici chili di felino, e si avviò verso il Metrò. Il Metrò era come sempre in sciopero, ma c'era una **fascia protetta** di quaranta secondi, e lei sperava di beccarla.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "fascia protetta" riferita a uno sciopero, come viene adoperata in questo brano. L'ho cercata alla voce "fascia" di parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovarla. Ricercando su Google "*fascia protetta*" *sciopero* mi appaiono parecchie occorreneze. Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Durante uno sciopero, in particolare nel settore dei trasporti, per *"fascia protetta"* si intende un intervallo orario in cui i servizi sono comunque garantiti (anche se magari in modo ridotto) in modo da non lasciare gli utenti del tutto privi di servizio; si parla anche di *"fascia garantita"* o *"fascia oraria garantita"* (o *di garanzia*).

Vedi ad es. https://www.atm.it/it/ViaggiaConNoi/Pagine/orari_calendario.aspx

> [...] In caso di sciopero il servizio si effettua nelle **fasce orarie di garanzia** previste dalla legge ossia dall’inizio del servizio fino alle 8.45 e dalle 15.00 alle 18.00 [...];

Nel brano in questione immagino che

> fascia protetta di quaranta secondi

sia in realtà usato in modo iperbolico (quaranta secondi sono un tempo ridicolmente corto!)

Comment: Veramente in questo romanzo ci sono molte cose esagerate.